# Problems solved by a second passport

Tags: discussion

We are getting questions along the lines of *"my passport is in the consulate for a visa, but I need it now for ...".* As I understand it, this is exactly why countries issue multiple passports to their citizens, but the concept seldom comes up.

- Usually it would be too late for the OP, but we're striving to give general answers, right?
- Is there any evidence that the disjointed travel history from having two passport booklets would cause problems with subsequent applications?
- Just how common/difficult is getting a second passport for expats?

Comment: This sounds like a Travel.SE question, not a Meta question

Comment: @JonathanReez, my question is if one should mention this in *answers* at Travel.SE, as in *"consider getting a second passport to solve your problem."* Before I suggest something like that, without having done it myself, I'd like to hear comments.

Comment: First find out whether the country does allow its citizens to get a second passport. Not all countries do as far as I remember.

Comment: @Willeke Canada does not.  You must turn in your existing passport to renew, and it is invalidated.  If it was lost or stolen, you must sign an affidavit to that effect and the old one is invalidated.

Comment: @Willeke, even if it is allowed, how do visa officials react when the passport contains only part of the travel history? Many visa forms ask about having a second citizenship, but do they ask about two booklets for one passport?

Comment: I've never heard of any country issuing valid password duplicate to their citizens.

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g, [Germany](https://www.bundestag.de/blob/508022/def9e1a0099bc2909bfa9ed98cf66422/wd-3-061-17-pdf-data.pdf) issues multiple passports if the bearer can explain the need. Examples include one passport with stamps as a NATO military dependent and one without, so the family of a deployed soldier does not have to identify themselves as such in third countries. *Another example is frequent travel while visa applications are pending, this must have been a problem in the past to get a second passport.*